Why do certain letters in the Greek and Hebrew languages share names?
My understanding is that Hebrew and Greek don't share a great deal in terms of their roots through history.
With that in mind, why do Aleph/Alpha and Beit/Beta, along with at least one or two other letters in their alphabets, share names?
Thanks!

The Hebrew and Greek languages are unrelated, but their writing systems are related. Wikipedia has a table showing many of the related scripts.

Both the Greek alphabet and the Hebrew abjad were adapted from the Phoenician abjad, and they inherited the letter names along with the letters. The genealogy of writing systems doesn't necessarily have anything in common with the genealogy of languages; the English alphabet is adapted from the Latin one, for example, but English is not descended from Latin.
In Phoenician (and Hebrew) these names were meaningful, as nouns starting with each consonant; originally, the letters were pictures of those things. In Greek they were meaningless, so they tended to be corrupted or eroded over time.
Somewhere in the transmission of the Greek alphabet to the Etruscans and then to the Romans, these names fell out of use, which is why the Latin alphabet doesn't use them.

Thank.you! Clear and easy to understand.
